# I need help identifying this language

Tags: language-identification

[image]

I noticed the swastika-like images along the sides and at first thought it was either Nordic or Hindi.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is definitely Asian

Comment: I think language identification questions are a bit of fun and I see no reason to ban them.

Comment: @jknappen. I agree, though the fun thing about these questions is the way that they invariably provoke a long string of ill-informed wild guesses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Gujarati to me. You can check by looking at the table of the Gujarati alphabet at http://www.omniglot.com/writing/gujarati.htm .

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this language! I would agree -- this seems to be what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a Brahmic script, though I am not sure which one.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmic_scripts